# Is there a way to download iis manager in Windows 7 Starter Edition?

Tags: windows, iis

I'm using Windows 7 Starter Edition. There isn't iis manager and typing inetmgr doesn't work. Is there a way to download IIS Manager? Not merely IIS but also IIS Manager.

Comment: Is that IIS7 installed using Programs and Features or did you install IIS 7 Express?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx).

You should activate the correct Windows features: `Internet Information Services` -> `Web Management Tools` -> `IIS Management Console`.

Maybe a reboot is required after that. Then you should be able to run `inetmgr`. If not, check whether you can find `inetmgr.exe` in the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` directory and run it directly from there.

Just to be sure, here you find a screenshot from the 'Windows Features' dialog:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Features dialog]

Comment: Answers that just point to an external source aren't good answers. What happens when Microsoft decides to reorganise that site and the link goes dark? This "answer" then becomes worse than useless.

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I have looked over windows features before. Those options are also selected. I currently have iis on computer but i don't have iis manager. I can't reason with that. Can i download iis manager seperately?

Comment: On the other hand, I don't like to repeat information that can already be found as a concise online resource. And Microsoft does a very good job of keeping links alive once they exist. But you do have a point so I'll add some more clues to my answer.

Comment: Updated answer based on suggestion by @ChrisF

Comment: There is not "inetmgr.exe" file in the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv directory. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

rwwilden has the correct answer. An alternative easy way to install it is using the [web installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).